# Submit form on checkbox change delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Goal:** I have a form with checkboxes that I want to submit on their .change() event. I want there to be a delay before submitting that is reset each time another checkbox is clicked.

**Code:**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#nav_form').submit();
    },750);
});
```

This code works but submits form too soon. And if I set the milliseconds to a higher value like a few seconds, it kinda works if users select many checkboxes but when they select just 1 or 2, the delay is really obvious.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the setTimeout - it is comparable to "debouncing" text entry in for example an Ajax controlled autocomplete.

```js
var tId;
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    clearTimeout(tId);
    tId=setTimeout(function(){
      $('#nav_form').submit();
    },750);
});
```

You may want to add a test if you only want to submit checked boxes:

```js
var tId;
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    clearTimeout(tId);
    if (('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length>0){
      tId=setTimeout(function(){
        $('#nav_form').submit();
      },750);
    }
});
```